# WIF in Azure WebSite

Tags: wif, azure-web-app-service

I would like to use Windows Identity foundation in an Azure WebSite. I noticed that Azure Websites support .Net 4.0 and not .Net 4.5. Does anyone know if there is a way to use WIF in an Azure WebSite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vittorio Bertocci (Mr. WIF himself) just posted a blog post on this topic:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2013/01/28/running-wif-based-apps-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

WIF 1.0 works fine in Azure - refer [How to implement single sign-on with Windows Azure Active Directory - ASP.NET Application](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/web-sso/).

Or you go go the Azure ACS route - Facebook etc.

Are you asking - "Does anyone know if there is a way to use WIF **4.5** in an Azure WebSite"?

Comment: Thanks... Yes, I am interested in WIF 4.5,

Answer (score 0):

This will be available approximately end of this month. Please sees http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/3fab0f32-23c9-4122-9ece-8c3edbadde47 for more detail, or check back in a couple weeks.

Thanks!